# Display string value real time

Tags: c#, multithreading, real-time

I'm writing a **console program**, and my code looks like this:

Configuration.cs

```
public static class Configuration
{
    public static string Message = "";
}
```

Menu.cs

```
class Menu
{
    public static void showMenu()
    {
        Console.Clear();
        Console.WriteLine("1: SOMETHING");
        Console.WriteLine("2: SOMETHING");
        Console.WriteLine("3: SOMETHING");
        Console.WriteLine("SYSTEM MSG: " + Configuration.Message);
        Console.Write("INPUT: ");
    }
}
```

Program.cs

```
...
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    ...
    int choice;

    while(true)
    {
        Menu.showMenu();
        choice = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

        switch(choice)
        {
            case 1:
            Configuration.Message = "HELLO!";
            break;

            case 2:
            Configuration.Message = "HI!";
            break;

            case 3:
            Configuration.Message = "WHAT?!";
            break;
        }
    }
}
...
```

For now, when I change Configuration.Message, it will display on the menu because the showMenu method clears the console and show the string again.

But what I want to make is without Clear method, I want to show Configuration.Message for real time.  I was thinking that using Timer and refresh the menu every second, but it is not efficient (feels like cheating).  How can I do this?

Comment: Console messages and displaying real time strings are not compatible ideas.  A Winforms or WPF app can display in real time with user input because you have multiple threads.  The console really isnt built for that.

Comment: @paqogomez It's not the multiple threads that make it work in other types of GUIs, it's the fact that you have entirely different media for displaying output and gathering input.  The fact that consoles mix the two together is what causes problems.

Comment: Note that console/terminals input/output worked for people for long time... I think the issue here is OP relies on absolute default behavior of console which indeed hard to mix input and output - taking over input/output (even just printing into specific positions with `Console.SetCursorPosition`) would make it possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would suggest that if functionality like this is necessary it would be better to look at a UI technology like WPF.  But, that being said, maybe this would do what you wanted.  Showing the menu each time you set the Message.  I do not think when using the console there is a way to bind a variable to some message on the console.

```
    public static class Configuration
    {
        private static string _message;
        public static string Message 
        { 
            get
            {
                return _message;
            }
            set
            {
                _message = value;
                Menu.showMenu();
            }
        }
    }
```

**Edit**: to implement this using a property changed event you could do something like this.  Note, I am not implementing `INotifyPropertyChanged` as to keep the static class.

```
class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Configuration.PropertyChanged += (sender, e) =>
            {
                Menu.showMenu();
            };
            int choice;

            while (true)
            {
                Menu.showMenu();
                choice = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

                switch (choice)
                {
                    case 1:
                        Configuration.Message = "HELLO!";
                        break;

                    case 2:
                        Configuration.Message = "HI!";
                        break;

                    case 3:
                        Configuration.Message = "WHAT?!";
                        break;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    class Menu
    {
        public static void showMenu()
        {
            Console.Clear();
            Console.WriteLine("1: SOMETHING");
            Console.WriteLine("2: SOMETHING");
            Console.WriteLine("3: SOMETHING");
            Console.WriteLine("SYSTEM MSG: " + Configuration.Message);
            Console.Write("INPUT: ");
        }
    }

    public static class Configuration 
    {
        public static event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        private static string _message;
        public static string Message
        {
            get
            {
                return _message;
            }
            set
            {
                if (value != _message)
                {
                    _message = value;
                    NotifyPropertyChanged(property: _message);
                }
            }
        }

        private static void NotifyPropertyChanged(object property, String propertyName = "")
        {
            if (PropertyChanged != null)
            {
                PropertyChanged(property, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: +1. `Menu` should definitely be dependency, not static call... Or even implement and wire up `INotifyPropertyChanged`. But ok as starting point.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov I agree that `INotifyPropertyChanged` would be a cleaner way to do this, especially if there were going to be any more members on `Configuration` class that Message.

Comment: When working with the console, especially when using `readLine`, you should be very careful to control your writes so that they don't happen while reading.  Putting the call to `showMenu`, which writes to the console, inside the `Configuration` class breaks this model and obfuscates the flow of writing text to the console.  It is not recommended.

Comment: @ErickRobertson that is a good point. I would suggest the same as you that if functionality like this is necessary it would be best to look at a UI technology like WPF.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov I added an edit with the Configuration class using a `PropertyChangedEvent`

Comment: @DROPTABLEusers One more question. Is there any way to refresh only Configuration.Message (not refreshing menu)?

Answer (score 4):

When you write to the `Console`, the write operation begins at the current cursor position. So...

Look at the properties and methods of the [`System.Console`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.console%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) class, in particular:

- `CursorLeft` gets or sets the column position of the cursor
- `CursorTop` gets or sets the row position of the cursor
- `SetCursorPosition( int left , int top )` sets both row and column position.

As each character is written, the cursor moves one position to the right, wrapping to the next row when the cursor would move past the `BufferWidth` column (e.g. if you're console's buffer is 80 columns wide, writing the 80th column would advance the column outside the buffer (column 81), so the cursor would move to column 1 of the next row.

For what you want to do, you could also look at P/Invoking the native Win32 cursor methods, or use something like one of the .Net derivations of *nix's [`curses(3)`](http://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=ncurses&sektion=3&apropos=0&manpath=FreeBSD%207.0-RELEASE) and Gnu's [`ncurses(3)`](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/ncurses.html):

- Mono-Curses: http://www.mono-project.com/MonoCurses
- Curses Sharp: http://curses-sharp.sourceforge.net/
- Curses X: http://www.csharpcity.com/2013/consolecurses-library-for-c/

Comment: +1 This is certainly the fully-featured way to go.  I would strongly recommend you ensure that all console interaction is done in the same thread.  No matter which solution you pick, this will ensure that you can create the best possible user experience.

Answer (score 3):

**Make the menu appear when the user hits enter.**

It is not a good idea to write to the console except in response to input from the user.  The reason for this is that you might write to the console in the middle of them typing out the line they want.  Then their text and backspace keys will become out of synch, and it will become difficult for the user to understand what's going on.

My recommendation would be to add another option so the user can just hit `ENTER` without a choice and it will re-display the menu without the clear.  This will allow the user to decide when they want to refresh in realtime by just hitting `ENTER` and not selecting an option.

If you truly want a more realtime approach, and want to mix it with user input, I would suggest that the console is not a good way to deliver this solution.